# What is wrong with my restful api YII2?

Tags: php, api, yii2

My code structure:

- `config/`
- `controllers/`
- `models/`
- `api-data/`

  - `config/`

    - `api.php`
  - `modules/`

    - `v1/`

      - `controllers/`

        - `ProgramStudiController.php`
      - `module.php`
  - `index.php`
  - `.htaccess`

Here is `api.php`:

```
    <?php

$db     = require(__DIR__ . '/../../config/db.php');
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'name' => 'TimeTracker',
    // Need to get one level up:
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__).'/..',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // Enable JSON Input:
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                     // Create API log in the standard log dir
                     // But in file 'api.log':
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/api.log',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'v1/programstudi'],
            ],
        ], 
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [

            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api-data\modules\v1\Module', // here is our v1 modules
            'controllerNamespace' => 'app\modules\v1\controllers',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

return $config;
```

`index.php`:

```
 <?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

// Use a distinct configuration for the API
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/api.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

`.htaccess`:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

`module.php`:

```
    <?php
// Check this namespace:
namespace api-data\modules\v1;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // ...  other initialization code ...
    }
}
```

`ProgramStudiController.php`:

```
    <?php
namespace \api-data\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class ProjectController extends ActiveController
{
    // We are using the regular web app modules:
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\ProgramStudi';
}
```

I call with http://localhost/sbmptn/api-data/v1/programstudi, but the response is 404. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I did some basic reformatting of your question. Nested bullets can be a good way to show a directory tree. You can do this by prefixing each item with `* ` and indenting with four spaces for each level.

Comment: oke thanksfor your info , iam a newbie in here

Answer (score 0):

You named conroller as `ProgramStudiController` and then class `ProjectController`. Rename it and use url like `/api-data/v1/program-studi`, with `-` sign, because you used camelcase in controller name.

Btw, you should create main controller in `controllers/` folder and then extend it in `api-data/modules/v1/controllers`.

Comment: thanks for your answer  , can you help me to give some example of main controller , im is newbie in yii2 ?

Comment: Main controller is normal controller where u put all actions, and then just extend this controller in `api-data/v1/controllers`, so u will inherit all methods from main controller and, if needed, u can override (in this case u wont need this, its just app logic)